# How to setup the Craft Commerce store both front and back end

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, installation

We've a requirement to setup Craft Commerce store as part of our testing, in this process we've gone through the documentation and found that we need to use HTML, CSS or JS code to complete the store setup.

Could anyone please help us how to setup the store?

Comment: Hi Lalitha, welcome to Stack Exchange! As it stands currently, this question is incredibly broad, and may be closed as "too broad". I'd actually recommend asking this question in the [Craft Slack channel](https://craftcms.com/community), or read more about [where to hire a Craft developer](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/12554/where-can-i-find-someone-to-help-build-my-craft-website).

Comment: We've succeeded in setuping the store and tried to place the order, with the dummy payment gateway as our site is Unlicensed and observed '404 Error File Not Found

The page you are looking for might have been removed, 
had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.'

Comment: We've succeeded in setuping the store and tried to place the order, with the dummy payment gateway as our site is Unlicensed and observed '404 Error File Not Found
We've succeeded in setuping the store and tried to place the order, with the dummy payment gateway as our site is Unlicensed and observed

 '404 Error File Not Found

The page you are looking for might have been removed, 
had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.' error on clicking on the 'PayNow' with dummy credit card number '4929000000006'.

Could you please help how to resolve this???

Comment: I'd recommend opening a new thread with your specific question.

Answer (score 2):

You might need a web developer to install Craft and Craft Commerce 'locally' (on your computer), using a testing domain such at **craftcommercedemo.dev**

Using the '.dev' [TLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain) will allow you to unlock Craft Pro and Craft Commerce so that you can see and test all of the CraftCMS + Commerce features.

Both Craft and Craft Commerce come with a set of **template files**, allowing you to **interact with the site in the same way a regular visitor would** (from the front end).

As a starting point, check out [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) (if you use a PC) or [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/) (if you use a Mac)

The above facilitates local Apache web server, plus MySQL database which will allow you to run Craft on your computer in the same way as you would on a real web server.

If you need a developer, check out this list of [Craft Professionals...](https://straightupcraft.com/professionals)

Hope that helps