# Developers Needed

Tags: ecommerce

We are in the midst of building a few sites in craft and one in craft commerce; need some additional resources to get them completed.  Please message me back with some details of your experience / availability and hourly rate. Cheers Rob

Comment: Hi Rob, this isn't a job board. See [this other thread](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/12554/45) for information on where to find a developer.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend you join the Craft Slack and post this in the #jobs channel, you might get a better response!

https://craftcms.com/community#slack