# Developers or experts for Craft CMS V3 in Costa Rica

Tags: craft3

I am looking for a Craft CMS developer in Costa Rica to help us with occasional issues

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find someone to help build my Craft website?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/12554/where-can-i-find-someone-to-help-build-my-craft-website)

Answer (score 1):

The best places to look for this are [workwithcraft.com](https://www.workwithcraft.com) and the [Craft CMS Discord](https://craftcms.com/discord) #jobs channel